# SapUI5 how can I navigate to a page after validating data within onInit?

Tags: redirect, sapui5

In my app, I have a complex page that doesn't want to be run unless search criteria have been input on a previous page. The validation is easy, but if I do a getRouter.navTo within the onInit function, my target page runs it's onInit, but the view that get's rendered is that of the page that I redireced from.

I have found that I can get this to work by using window.setTimeOut to defer the navTo until after the onInit, but there surely is a better way that this isn't there?

It would be ideal if the first page didn't even render, with the second page being the only one visible.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your problem, but if you need a search criteria to route to a certain view, why dont you decide on that view where you are routing to depending on the state of the search criteria?

Comment: So when the Criteria form is submitted I navigate to the search result page, and as you say, I could validate/decide at that point. The target page validates that there is a criteria object in the component view. My problem is when the app is started with the result page's hash, I can't detect absence of criteria and redirect in onInit - it renders the wrong page and gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the first page to be rendered, you can do your validation in the onBeforeRendering method. That way you can execute your validation before your page is rendered.